# How can i get chemical element list?

Tags: python

I'd like to share something with a chemical formula. For example

C14H19NO, C10H12O2, C15H26O

to

{"C14","H19","N","O","C10","H12","O2","C15","H26","O"} like this

I also want to know how to process .txt at once please help me..

```
num=["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0"]

text=input("C9H8Cl3")
lis=list(text)

for i in range(len(text)):
    if lis[i] in num: lis[i]=int(lis[i])
    

lis2=lis[:]

k=1
for i in range(len(text)-1):
    if type(lis[i])==int and type(lis[i+1])==str:
        lis2.insert(i+k, "|")
        k+=1

for i in range(len(lis2)):
    if type(lis2[i])==int: lis2[i]=str(lis2[i])
    
result=""
for  i in range(len(lis2)):
    result+=lis2[i]
    
print(result)
```

```
I tried this, but only one can be converted at a time, and neither is converted.

I want another code.. help me
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. To me is not clear what your actual problem is, like possible errors or outputs you actually get.
In general you might want to work with *regex* to capture LetterNumber groupings. Which will probably be easier to use in the long run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, we can use `re.findall` here:

```py
import re

inp = ["C14H19NO", "C10H12O2", "C15H26O"]
for f in inp:
    atoms = re.findall(r'[A-Z][a-z]?[0-9]*', f)
    print(atoms)
```

This prints:

```
['C14', 'H19', 'N', 'O']
['C10', 'H12', 'O2']
['C15', 'H26', 'O']
```